# `.background` goes wrong in `.background()` modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a `ButtonStyle`. I want to let the background color be `buttonBackgroundHover` color which is already created in `Assets.xcassets`, and other time remains the default background color (same as the background color of the window). So I tried the code below, but Xcode said an error: `Member 'background(ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)' expects argument of type 'Color'`

```
struct PlayerButton: ButtonStyle {

    @State private var isOnHover: Bool = false

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(isOnHover ? Color("buttonBackgroundHover") : .background)
    }
}
```

But if I replace `.background(isOnHover ? Color("buttonBackgroundHover") : .background)` with `.background(.background)`, there's no argue. I wonder what's wrong with that and how can I solve this problem. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background` method is declared like this:

```
func background<S>(_ style: S, ignoresSafeAreaEdges edges: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View where S : ShapeStyle
```

Notice that the argument it takes is of type `S` where `S : ShapeStyle`. When you do `.background(.red)` or `.background(.background)`, `S` is `Color` or `BackgroundStyle` respectively.

However, when you pass in:

```
isOnHover ? Color("buttonBackgroundHover") : .background
```

There is no single type `S` that works. You want `S` to be *either* `Color` *or* `BackgroundStyle`, but the type of the above expression can only be one type of those types. The compiler sees that since `Color("buttonBackgroundHover")` is of type `Color`, it mistakenly thinks that you want the third operand `.background` to be of type `Color` too. But there is no such property as `Color.background`, but since `Color` is a view, it has a `background` method too, and that is what `.background` gets resolved to. It expects a `Color` argument, because you are calling an instance method without an instance (`Color.background`).

Anyway, there is a type eraser for `ShapeStyle` - `AnyShapeStyle`. Apply that to make both branches of the conditional expression the same type:

```
.background(isOnHover ? AnyShapeStyle(Color("buttonBackgroundHover")) : AnyShapeStyle(.background))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no color `Color.background` - it tries to apply same `.background()` modifier, but there is Color first in ternary operator, so types conflict - error.

I assume it was expected

```
.background(isOnHover ? Color("buttonBackgroundHover") : 
                        Color(uiColor: UIColor.systemBackground))  // << this !!
```

Comment: Thanks. But what about if my target is macOS. As UIKit can not be used for macOS and all of `.textBackgroundColor`, `.controlBackgroundColor`, `.underPageBackgroundColor` and `.windowBackgroundColor` in `NSColor` have subtle difference from the real background color of my window. Is there any solution?

Comment: You had to mention that it is for macOS, anyway find a color which fits your needs, but that's actually different question.